# Upload Multiple Files in parallel in android

Tags: android, file-upload, android-asynctask

How to upload multiple Files (Images , video ) in parallel to server in android with displaying percentage . currently i can upload only one file at time with displaying percentage.  I try to search but i can not get proper solution. so,please any one help or suggest me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AsyncTask for uploading. For every file make new instance of AsyncTask and execute it. For executing use this

```
void startMyTask(AsyncTask asyncTask) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    else
        asyncTask.execute(params);
}
```

otherwise AsyncTasks won't run parallel.

Comment: k i will try and den inform to u.